# How to subtract timestamp and plot in Python?

Tags: python

I have two text files (file1.txt and file2.txt).

file1.txt has list of start timestamp value like:

```
1488407827454
1488407827485
1488407827554
1488407827584
1488407827654
```

file2.txt has list of end timestamp value like:

```
    1488407827954
    1488407827985
    1488407827994
    1488407827997
    1488407829999
```

How to subtract end time stamp from start time stamp from these two files to get actual list of time in millisecond in python and plot CDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
# Read and subtract the timestamps
timediff = []

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
        f1_lines = f1.readlines()
        f2_lines = f2.readlines()


f1_nums = map(int, f1_lines)
f2_nums = map(int, f2_lines)

for t1 in f1_nums:
    for t2 in f2_nums:
        timediff.append(t2-t1)

# plot the CDF
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array(timediff)

# Choose how many bins you want here
num_bins = 20

# Use the histogram function to bin the data
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins=num_bins, normed=True)

# Now find the cdf
cdf = np.cumsum(counts)

# And finally plot the cdf
plt.plot(bin_edges[1:], cdf)

plt.show()
```

Produces:
[image]

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Perfect

Comment: Cool, glad it helped you (and thanks for accepting!) cheers :)